# Find out closest date to a particular date in a row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with multiple dates and main date (dm).I have to find out closest date to the main date in MS SQL script.e.g. In the below table d1 is closest to dm.

```
d1         |d2        |dm        |d3        |d4        |d5
2015.05.06 |2015.10.06|2015.05.05|2015.01.06|2015.06.06|2015.08.06
```

Comment: Do You need just date or also information if it was d1 or d4?

Comment: What is the output you want?  Are these really stored in the same row?

Comment: 2015.05.06  in above case

Comment: Why are your dates stored in a difficult format (apparently as `varchar`)?

Comment: No, it's datetime. Any datetime format is ok for me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually you are right, they are not stored like that.They are in 2 columns , one with dm and rest in another columns.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, `apply` is probably the easier method:

```
select t.*, dd.d as closest_date, dd.dname as closest_date_column
from t cross apply
     (select top 1 v.*
      from (values (d1, 'd1'), (d2, 'd2'), (d3, 'd3'), (d4, 'd4')) v(d, dname)
      order by abs(datediff(day, v.d, t.dm))
     ) dd;
```

Comment: what is d.* and t.d ? I've got syntax error with d.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (d1 DATETIME, d2 DATETIME, d3 DATETIME, d4 DATETIME,d5 DATETIME, dm DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @Tbl
SELECT
    '2015.05.06',
    '2015.10.09',   
    '2015.01.06',
    '2015.06.06',
    '2015.08.06',
    '2015.05.05'


SELECT
    *,
    (SELECT TOP 1 A.d
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, T.dm, T.d1)) a, T.d1 d union all
        SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, T.dm, T.d2)) a, T.d2 d union all
        SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, T.dm, T.d3)) a, T.d3 d union all
        SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, T.dm, T.d4)) a, T.d4 d union all
        SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, T.dm, T.d5)) a, T.d5 d
    ) A ORDER BY A.a) ClosestDate
FROM
    @Tbl T
```

Result

```
d1          d2          d3          d4          d5          dm          ClosestDate
2015-05-06  2015-10-09  2015-01-06  2015-06-06  2015-08-06  2015-05-05  2015-05-06
```